# What are some interesting applications of Yoneda's lemma in (functional) analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, homological-algebra, yoneda-lemma

I recently took a class in homological algebra and there I saw Yoneda's lemma. This says that if we have a locally small category $C$ and a functor $F:C\to\text{Set}$, then the natural transformations of $\text{Hom}(-,X)$ to $F$ are a set, more precisely we have a bijection between the natural transformations of $\text{Hom}(-,X)\to F$ and the set $FX$.

Now I am mostly interested in analytic aspects of mathematics but I feel that the above lemma is very widely applicable, to the point that I cannot grasp its potential. I was wondering, does anybody know of an application of Yoneda's lemma that produces an interesting result for some analytic objects, e.g. Banach spaces, Hilbert spaces?

I am new to this site so please tell me if my question is not suitable or if I must edit something.

Comment: Related : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83363/is-there-a-nice-application-of-category-theory-to-functional-complex-harmonic-an/83382

Comment: Not the Yoneda lemma specifically, but Scholze has an inspiring message in the introduction of his [lecture notes on analytic geometry](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf): "For some reason, this secret plot [of algebraic geometers] has so far stopped short of taking over analysis.  The goal of this course is to launch a new attack, turning functional analysis into a branch of commutative algebra..." in order to apply "the highly categorical techniques of algebraic geometry".